# bash scripting: if condition

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I am passing command line arguments to a script, say a.sh.

From a.sh, I use "$@" to pass all those arguments to another bash script (user_pref.sh). In this bash file, I am trying to assign either 0 or 1 based on the parameters received from a.sh using basic if condition. But for some reason, I am not able to reason the correct value and all my variables are set to 0. I am new to bash scripting and would really appreciate any help here. I have referred different post on the site but they have not helped me resolve my issue so far.

a.sh code

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/postgres/viraltest_scripts/user_pref.sh "$@" &> /home/postgres/viraltest_scripts/logs/refresh_dev_sql.log
```

user_pref.sh Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
## assigning default values
a=1
b=1
c=1
if [[ $1 -eq 0 ]]
then
    a=0
fi

if [[ $2 -eq 0 ]]
then
    b=0
fi

if [[ $3 -eq 0 ]]
then
    c=0
fi
```

Irrespective of what I pass from a.sh, All the variables in user_pref.sh are assigned 0. Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong with the If statement? 
PS: I am aware of assigning a=$1 but for the purpose of my application, I have to explicitly assign 0 or 1 instead of doing a=$1.

Comment: Are you passing arguments that are integers?  `[[ non_integer_value -eq 0 ]]` is true and does not emit any error message.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46978494/edit) to include the relevant portions of `a.sh`?  It is difficult to know exactly what you are trying to accomplish otherwise.  Thanks!

Comment: I am passing only integers, 0 and 1 specifically.

Comment: @cxw I have edited the question with the a.sh file. Thank you for such prompt reply :)

Comment: What shell is this? `/bin/sh` may not be what you think it is. If you want bash, say so. Try running with `bash -x a.sh` to see what's happening.

Comment: `[[ ]]` is not the only syntax used here and not guaranteed to be available in `/bin/sh`; `&>` is a bashism as well.

Comment: I have changed the bash to /bin/bash and the problem still remains the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** The first line of your file should be `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`.  You are using bash extensions, so make sure you are asking that the script be interpreted by bash (and not sh, dash, csh, ...).

Second, `-eq` tests for *numeric* equality, not *string* equality.  As a result, `[[ '' -eq 0 ]]` is true.  I think you may want `[[ $# -ge 1 && $1 = 0 ]]`, and similar tests throughout.  `$# -ge 1` checks if a parameter was actually provided, and then `=` tests for string equality.  Like this:

```
a=1
if [[ $# -ge 1 && $1 = 0 ]]; then a=0 ; fi
b=1
if [[ $# -ge 2 && $2 = 0 ]]; then b=0 ; fi
c=1
if [[ $# -ge 3 && $3 = 0 ]]; then c=0 ; fi
```

**Edit 2** Not sure if this meets your requirements, but since you are only passing `0` or `1`, you can use default assignments:

```
a="${1:-1}"
b="${2:-1}"
c="${3:-1}"
```

`"${foo:-def}"` is a substitution with a default value.  If `$foo` is unset or null, `def` is the result; otherwise, `$foo` is the result.

#### Test

Per the OP's comment:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash
./user_pref.sh "$@"

$ cat user_pref.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -x
a=1
if [[ $# -ge 1 && $1 = 0 ]]; then a=0 ; fi
b=1
if [[ $# -ge 2 && $2 = 0 ]]; then b=0 ; fi
c=1
if [[ $# -ge 3 && $3 = 0 ]]; then c=0 ; fi
echo a-"$a"- b-"$b"- c-"$c"

$ ./a.sh
+ a=1
+ [[ 0 -ge 1 ]]
+ b=1
+ [[ 0 -ge 2 ]]
+ c=1
+ [[ 0 -ge 3 ]]
+ echo a-1- b-1- c-1
a-1- b-1- c-1
```

A case giving it a `1` manually (even though `1` is the default):

```
$ ./a.sh 1
+ a=1
+ [[ 1 -ge 1 ]]       <--- it saw the parameter
+ [[ 1 = 0 ]]
+ b=1
+ [[ 1 -ge 2 ]]
+ c=1
+ [[ 1 -ge 3 ]]
+ echo a-1- b-1- c-1
a-1- b-1- c-1
```

The case I think the OP is referring to:

```
$ ./a.sh 0
+ a=1
+ [[ 1 -ge 1 ]]       <--- it saw the parameter...
+ [[ 0 = 0 ]]
+ a=0                 <--- ...and it overrode the default.
+ b=1
+ [[ 1 -ge 2 ]]
+ c=1
+ [[ 1 -ge 3 ]]
+ echo a-0- b-1- c-1
a-0- b-1- c-1

$ ./a.sh 0 0 0
+ a=1
+ [[ 3 -ge 1 ]]
+ [[ 0 = 0 ]]
+ a=0
+ b=1
+ [[ 3 -ge 2 ]]
+ [[ 0 = 0 ]]
+ b=0
+ c=1
+ [[ 3 -ge 3 ]]
+ [[ 0 = 0 ]]
+ c=0
+ echo a-0- b-0- c-0
a-0- b-0- c-0
```

Comment: the if condition always returns false even when a parameter is 0. I checked by running set -x, it reads 
[[ $# -ge 1 && $1 = 0 ]]
to [[ 0 -ge 1 ]] and then skips the rest of the if statement

Comment: @vsh9 When running `./a.sh`?  If you don't pass any parameters, you'll get the default values (`1`).  See edit.

Comment: Your suggestion works. Thanks a lot for your help. I have marked your comment as my answer!

Comment: I did, it should be visible

Comment: @vsh9 yep, it is now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
a=$(( $# > 0 ))
b=$(( $# > 1 ))
c=$(( $# > 2 ))
```

`$#` is the number of positional parameters received. If `$# > 0`, you know you got at least one argument, so `a` should be 1, or 0 otherwise. In an arithmetic expression, a true boolean value evaluates to 1, a false to 0. Likewise, if `$#` is at least 2, then `b` should be 1, etc.

If you are certain that the passed parameters will be 0 or 1, and you simply want to default to 0 if a parameter is missing, use

```
a=${1:-0}
b=${2:-0}
c=${3:-0}
```

in which each parameter expansion evaluates to 0 if the given parameter is null or unset.

Answer (score 0):

Seems easier to do:

```
test -z "$1"
a=$?
test -z "$2"
b=$?
test -z "$3"
c=$?
```

(This implements the logic that I *think* you are trying to get at.  Namely, assign the value 1 if the respective parameter is non-empty, 0 otherwise.)